# PowerShell add field codes to ms word footer

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have field codes set up in some documents which will display the current date when it is printed, but be invisible the rest of the time, as far as I know. I now need to apply this footer to hundreds of documents. It seems like this should be possible to do with PowerShell, but I don't really know how to use it, and can't find a good reference/documentation (So far I have gotten it to open a document, replace text, and close the document). I would like the following Field Code to be on the right side of every footer section:

{ IF{PRINTDATE \@ "M/d/yyyy h:mm"}={DATE  \@ "M/d/yyyy h:mm"} "UNCONTROLLED COPY AS OF { DATE \@"M/d/yyyy"}" "         "

I know that is probably a terrible way to do that, but, the real question is, how do you add field codes to footers in Word 2007 documents using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to crobin1 at tek-tips for the answer to this one. He said he referenced  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258930%28v=office.12%29.aspx and a bunch of "Hey, Scripting Guy!" blog entries

Here is an example script that pretty much does what I wanted.

> function Edit-Footer
>   ([string]$Document) {
>
> ```
> add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" 
>
> #Variables used
> set-variable -name wdAlignPageNumberCenter -value 1
> ```
>
> -option constant
>
> ```
> $fc1 = @" IF {PRINTDATE \@ "M/d/yyyy h:mm"}={DATE \@ "M/d/yyyy h:mm"} "UNCONTROLLED COPY AS OF {DATE \@ "M/d/yyyy"}" " " "@
>
>
> $Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
> $Word.Visible = $True
> #$Word.Visible = $False
>
> $fc2 = [ref] "" -as [Type]
>
> $OpenDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
> $c = $OpenDoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter)
> $range1 = $openDoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).range
> $field1 = $OpenDoc.Fields.Add($range1, -1, $fc2)
> $field1.Code.Text = $fc1
> $field1.Update
>
> #$OpenDoc.Close() }
> ```