# Odd and even pages footer - page X of Y in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to generate word documents in Powershell with different footer on even and odd pages.

I would like to have text with data on left side, and `Page X of Y` on right side on one page and reverse combination on next page.

First problem is in `X of Y` format. And second problem I have with placing text with field in one footer. If I put field, the text was disappear, and when I put text, field was disappearing.

[PowerShell add field codes to ms word footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316157/powershell-add-field-codes-to-ms-word-footer) - does not work in my case.

I will be grateful for your help.

```
$dat = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.add()
$doc.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = $true
$selection = $word.Selection
# ...
# content
# ...
$section = $doc.sections.item(1)
$footer = $section.Footers(1)
$Range = $footer.Range
$Range.Text = "Some text($dat)"
$Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
$footer.PageNumbers.Add(2)
$Range.Font.Size = 10

$footer = $section.Footers(3)
$Range = $footer.Range
$Range.Text = "Some text($dat)"
$Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
$footer.PageNumbers.Add(0)
$Range.Font.Size = 10

$outputPath = 'C:\FileToDocx.docx'  
$doc.SaveAs($outputPath)
$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

The problem is also that the `$footer.PageNumbers.Add()` is global and it does not depend from my odd and even footer range.

Also I was tried resolve my problem by swap PageNumbers to combination of `$Range.Fields.Add($Range, 26)` and `$Range.Fields.Add($Range, 33)`, e.g.

```
$fieldsPage = $Range.Fields.Add($Range, 33)
$sumField = $fieldsPage.Result.Text
$fieldsNumPages = $Range.Fields.Add($Range, 26)
$sumField += ' of ' + $fieldsNumPages.Result.Text
$range.Text = "Some text($dat)`t`tPage $sumField"
```

but in this case I have static string. I don't know how to use this two type of fields with static text with `$dat` in footer without conversion to string. The footer forces me to use fields, because only they can be different on each page.