# How Do I Remove An Existing Word Doc Watermark With Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I need to use PowerShell to remove a watermark from an existing Word doc. I'm attempting to convert the results of the Word macro recorder to PowerShell but am getting a "[System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Shapes'" error. Any help is appreciated. The PS code is below.

```
$Word=New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$wdSeekPrimaryHeader = 1
$Doc=$Word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mynamehere\Downloads\andSuch\SampleDoc1.docx")
$Selection=$Word.Selection
$Doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView=$wdSeekPrimaryHeader
$Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("PowerPlusWaterMarkObject357476642").Select
$Selection.ShapeRange.Delete
$Doc.Save()
$Doc.Close()
$Word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution, cobbled together from ["Hey, Scripting Guy!"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-manipulating-word-and-excel-with-powershell/) entries and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316157/powershell-add-field-codes-to-ms-word-footer?noredirect=1&lq=1) about PowerShell and Word footers.

```
Function OpenWordDoc($Filename)
{
$Word = NEW-Object –ComObject Word.Application
Return $Word.documents.open($Filename)
}

$Doc = OpenWordDoc -Filename "C:\Users\mynamehere\Downloads\andSuch\WaterMarkDoc.docx"
$Savename = "C:\Users\mynamehere\Downloads\andSuch\SansWaterMarkDoc.docx"

[void]$Doc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).range.Delete(1)

Function SaveAsWordDoc($Document,$FileName)
{
$Doc.Saveas([REF]$Filename)
$Doc.Close()
}
SaveAsWordDoc –document $Doc –Filename $Savename
```

Answer (score 0):

Show your code?

A simple search for your use case 'PowerShell and Microsoft word remove watermark' would give you a list, and even full scripts for exactly what you are after. For example, this one is about adding a Watermark. Of course removing is, you'd reverse the logic.

[How to Watermark Word Documents with PowerShell](https://www.erickscottjohnson.com/blog--examples/how-to-watermark-word-documents-with-powershell)

```
#Relevant files
$File = $args[0]
$WM = $args[1]

#Open document in Word
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $False
$Doc  = $Word.Documents.Open($File)

#Insert Watermark
Function Watermark
{
    #Create rectangle
    $Shape = $args[0].Shapes.AddShape(1,0, 0, 500, 125)

    #Fill rectanlge with watermark image
    $PicFill = $Shape.Fill.UserPicture($args[1])

    #Hide rectangle lines
    $Shape.Line.Visible = $False

    #Set transparency of watermark
    $Shape.Fill.Transparency = .8

    #Center watermark on width of page
    $Shape.Left = -999995

    #Center watermark on height of page (This was guess and checked)
    $Shape.Top = 250

    #Rotate watermark
    #Rotation rarely works when Word is not visible.  Command left here for reference.
    $Shape.Rotation = 315
}

#Only on 1st Page
#Watermark $Doc $WM

#On all Pages
#Determine number of pages in document
$Bind = 'System.Reflection.BindingFlags' -as [type]
$Doc.Repaginate()
$Prop = $Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(14)
$Pages = [System.__ComObject].invokemember('Value', $Bind::GetProperty, $null, $Prop, $null)

#Start at 0 to include any cover pages
For ($i = 0; $i -le $Pages - 1; $i ++)
{
    #Change pages
    $Word.Selection.GoTo(1,2,$null,$i)

    #Apply watermark
    Watermark $Doc $WM
}

#Check version of Word installed and save changes
$Version = $Word.Version
If ($Version -eq '16.0' -Or $Version -eq '15.0') {
    $Doc.Close($True)  
}
ElseIf ($Version -eq '14.0') {
    $Doc.Close([ref]$True)
}

#Exit Word
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$Word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)

#Cleanup
Remove-Variable Word
```

You could also, just ---

1. Opened any Word doc with a watermark.
2. Fire up the Word Macro recorder.
3. Do what you wish in Word.
4. Stop the recorder when done.
5. Export the macro code.
6. Convert the macro VBA code for use with PowerShell.